# Read from file with getline in a string then split the numbers from the string in int array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read from a .txt file some numbers separted by white space. ( max 4 numbers on a line).

- I get the line but how can I transform it into array of int then
  after I move to the second line to overwrite the array?

Example:
.txt file

```
2 5 8 14 11
50 40 30 20 10
18 17 16 15 14
```

Code:

```
fstream f("C:\\n.txt");
string wtf;
int n;
while(f>>n)
{
getline(f,wtf);
//transform the wtf string into int array?
//do what ever...
//clear the array?
}
```

Comment: You know guys you could downvote and tell the poor guy what's wrong with his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `std::istringstream` and `std::vector`:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(f, line)) {
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  std::vector<int> v;
  int i;
  while(iss > i) {
    v.push_back(i);
  }
  // do whatever
  // vector cleared automatically
}
```

Comment: Is there any way without vectors and push back function? Thank you

Comment: Yes, you could use `std::list<>`, or `std::array<>` (if you know the size a compile time), or even a naked array (although I wouldn't recommend that.)